# Liferay input-date format

Tags: java, date, jsp, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.2 and want to use a ***liferay-ui:input-date*** field. Field itself is working fine. However i want to change the displayed date Format from

*mm/dd/yyyy*

to

*dd.mm.yyyy*

But how to do this? I cant see any attibutes to set this...

```
<liferay-ui:input-date firstDayOfWeek="1"
        yearValue="<%=calendar.get(calendar.YEAR)%>"
        monthValue="<%=calendar.get(calendar.MONTH)%>"
        dayValue="<%=calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)%>" dayParam="dateFrom-day"
        monthParam="dateFrom-month" yearParam="dateFrom-year" />
```

Comment: did you to use `dateFormat: '%d.%m.%y'`

Comment: how to use it with <liferay-ui:input-date/> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the input-date taglib code and if you want to change the pattern you have to modify its code. Path to the file: \webapps\ROOT\html\taglib\ui\input_date\page.jsp. Simply you can replace this line:

`Format format = FastDateFormatFactoryUtil.getSimpleDateFormat(simpleDateFormatPattern, locale);`

with:

`Format format = FastDateFormatFactoryUtil.getSimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", locale);
mask = "%d.%m.%Y";`

and save the file. More elegant solution would be creating a hook on this component, but it's up to you.

Comment: @J000S do you still have the source code of that hook?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this tag displays the date according to the user's language choice. By default that's `en_US`, thus mm/dd/yyyy. If you set your user's default language (or your portal's) to `en_GB` (or `de`, for example), the format will be according to the language that's used on the UI.

Comment: didn't notice that... that works. But i then cant Change the / to . ?

Comment: I thought that that would be included in the format... You're on the latest 6.2 release, right? (plus: even that, if it's CE, is out of service already - you might also want to try on the latest 7.0 release)

Comment: I'm on 6.2 CE GA6... didnt know this is out of Service already (in fact we updated from 6.1 to 6.2 a few month ago). However we're using Liferay with BOSCH Inubit, so we might not ne able to upgrade to 7.0.

Comment: The update cycle for CE is: Only the latest major release is the one that gets updates - as soon as a later version is out, that's the one. This is different for the EE releases, which get updates for a defined time after release - where there are many in parallel. At least you're on the latest 6.2 CE release - I just wanted to make sure we're not hunting already fixed bugs here.