# Liferay input-date displaying letter "d"

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, liferay

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671323/liferay-input-date-format) i tried to change the date format of Liferays input-date field. So far successfull.
However i was testing it in different browsers and noticed that Firefox messes up the date when i click the field. No problems in IE or Chrome.

It initially displays the current date like ***18.08.2017***. But when i click the field (no change of the date that moment) it displays ***d.08.2017***.
At first i thought i messed it up due my format changes. But after undoing these the error still exists...

The value itself however is working normal and my java method doesnt get any erros. I can change the date in the picker and the hidden fields will have the correct value. Only the visible part of the date is messed up.

I looked into the console and saw, that Liferay.Form is undefined. I dont know if it's relevant at all. IE and Chrome are displaying errors too, but are also displaying the date normally.

```
Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
IE: unable to get property "get" of undefined or null reference
FF: TypeError: Liferay.Form is undefined
```

How can i get rid of this error?

**EDIT:**

That's the code i'm using for the datepicker:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
if(renderRequest.getAttribute("task") != null){
    String dateFrom = (String)renderRequest.getAttribute("DATE_FROM");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date date = format.parse(dateFrom);
    calendar.setTime(date);
}else{
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (GetterUtil.getInteger(portletPreferences.getValue("dateRange", "7"))*-1));
}%>
<liferay-ui:input-date firstDayOfWeek="1"
    yearValue="<%=calendar.get(calendar.YEAR)%>"
    monthValue="<%=calendar.get(calendar.MONTH)%>"
    dayValue="<%=calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)%>" dayParam="dateFrom-day"
        monthParam="dateFrom-month" yearParam="dateFrom-year" />
```

I don't have any js code, because i've written none.

Comment: Can you post your code...

Comment: Can you post some more info? I can't reproduce this bug. What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: I'm using FF 55.0.2 (32bit).
I replaced the `<liferay-ui:input-date>` with the alloy ui datepicker, Liferay comes with. This kinda looks the same. I guess Liferay is using alloy in the background for the input-date field...
However when i use the alloy ui version itself, even Chrome (latest) displays a wrong date.

Comment: I really want to help you. I tried that version of FF, latest Chrome and IE11 and i can't reproduce this bug. Maybe some other code is interrupting date picker. If you could figure out how to reproduce this bug, that would be great